# In an AngularJS expression is there a way to compare a scope value to a value in another library?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive around a third party library, to go in a form, where the option chosen in a select drop-down will bring up a different set of form elements.

In the parent element of each subset of form elements I'm trying to use an expression similar to this: `ng-if="myScopeObj.val === ThirdParty.CONSTANT_VAL"`.  I came to realize it's not working because the "ThirdParty" library isn't on the scope.

Should I just assign the library to a variable on the scope, or is there some pattern that can address this?  It seems like creating `isThis()` or `isThat()` functions for every constant in the library wouldn't be a great solution.

Should I create a service to wrap the third party library and then inject it into the directive?  Though I'd still need to put the injected service on the scope.  Would that be overkill for a library that doesn't access remote APIs?  I don't think it'd need to be mocked for testing, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you do need to get the value on the $scope somehow in order for it to be usable. And you're correct that one of the primary benefits of wrapping in a service is that you can mock the library. Another benefit of wrapping in a service is self-documentation. As someone else (or yourself at a later time) looking at your code, I could be confused as to where ThirdParty is coming from. Working in Angular, the assumption is that all dependencies are injected, and breaking convention comes at a cognitive cost. Having a service also can make it easier to swap out the underlying library later for a different implementation. Anyway, your simplest fix is:

```
$scope.ThirdParty = ThirdParty;
```